# Skip first match in file using Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have this file contains this kind of data

```
NAME: "Chassis", DESCR: "Nexus5020 Chassis"
PID: N5K-C5020P-BF     , VID: V04 , SN: SS613390FZT

NAME: "Module 1", DESCR: "40x10GE/Supervisor"
PID: N5K-C5020P-BF     , VID: V04 , SN: JA91344BHNK

NAME: "Module 2", DESCR: "6x10GE Ethernet Module"
PID: N5K-M1600         , VID: V01 , SN: JA71228018M

NAME: "Module 3", DESCR: "8x1/2/4G FC Module"
PID: N5K-M1008         , VID: V01 , SN: JAB1531020C
```

By using shell script, I managed to grab relevant data which are string in DESCR: and SN: and save it in csv file as below;

```
Nexus5020 Chassis,SS613390FZT
40x10GE/Supervisor,JA91344BHNK
6x10GE Ethernet Module,JA71228018M
8x1/2/4G FC Module,JAB1531020C
```

My question is what modification needed so the script will skip the first match for DESCR: and SN: so it will turn out like this in the output?

```
40x10GE/Supervisor,JA91344BHNK
6x10GE Ethernet Module,JA71228018M
8x1/2/4G FC Module,JAB1531020C
```

The script is here :

```
#/bin/bash

re_descr='DESCR: "([^"]+)"'
re_sn='SN: ([^[:space:]]+)'

while read -r; do
        if [[ $REPLY =~ $re_descr ]]; then
                descr=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
                continue
        fi
        if [[ $REPLY =~ $re_sn ]]; then
                sn=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
        fi
        if [[ $descr && $sn ]]; then
                printf '%s\t%s\n' "$descr","$sn"
                unset -v descr sn
        fi
done < <(cat <filename>)
```

Comment: If you've the result in a `.csv` file, and need to skip the first match, this might do: `awk 'NR>1 {print $0}' csv_file`

Comment: Thanks. I know that. But direct modification to the script is needed because it will cleanup multiple files which resulted in one csv file. If I use awk command to the file, result won't be the same since it has been processed earlier.

Comment: Simple answer: change `< <(cat <filename>)` to `< <(tail -n+3 <filename>)` Note: your use of `cat` is an *Unnecessary Use Of `cat`* (a *UUOc*). Never use *process substitution* to `cat` a file to feed a `while` loop. Simply `while read -r; do ... done <filename`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a variable `firstline` (init it as true). 
When you have `sn` and `descr` matched, set the var to `false`, else print.

EDIT: Alternative.

You can use tr and sed for manipulting the file.
First make sure that all lines (except the first) start with `DESCR`:

```
tr -d "\n" < file | sed 's/DESCR/\n&/g; $ s/$/\n/'
```

The first line is without `DESCR`, the second one is the one you want to ignore.
So process this stream from the third line:

```
tr -d "\n" < file | sed 's/DESCR/\n&/g; $ s/$/\n/' |
   sed -rn '3,$ s/DESCR: "([^"]+).*SN: ([^[:space:]]+).*/\1,\2/p'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace `done < <(cat <filename>)` by `done < <filename> | sed 1d`.

It looks like this (*with `/tmp/foo` as input file*):

```
#/bin/bash

re_descr='DESCR: "([^"]+)"'
re_sn='SN: ([^[:space:]]+)'

while read -r; do
        if [[ $REPLY =~ $re_descr ]]; then
                descr=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
                continue
        fi
        if [[ $REPLY =~ $re_sn ]]; then
                sn=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
        fi
        if [[ $descr && $sn ]]; then
                printf '%s\t%s\n' "$descr","$sn"
                unset -v descr sn
        fi
done < /tmp/foo | sed 1d
```

Comment: Just tried. It didn't work with multiple source file.

Comment: No, I would wrap this within a simple `for` loop to read several input files like this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the input to while loop from the end, pass the input as inner loop.

Try this to remove the first line for multiple input files

```
$ cat in.txt
line1
line2
line3
line4
$ perl -ne ' { print if $.>1 ; close(ARGV) if eof } ' in.txt in.txt | while read -r a ; do ; echo $a  ; done
line2
line3
line4
line2
line3
line4
$
```

I just used in.txt in.txt to show that it removes the first line..